# SharePoint Online Office 365 modern site

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server

How can I customize the page in modern site:

https://ericsson.sharepoint.com/sites/MELADS/SitePages/Home.aspx

I tried to search for Content editor WebPart or Script Editor WebPart but it is not present on current site. Kindly help on how can we enable the option to get this WebPart or any other way to add JavaScript to the page.

Answer (score 0):

There is no **Script Editor WebPart**   or  **Content Editor WebPart** even **JSLink** in modern page instead you should customize your modern page by [SharePoint Framework](https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/spfx/sharepoint-framework-overview) .

> **Note** :
>
> - > We don't recommend combining the "**modern**" page functionality with
>   >     "**classic**" SharePoint publishing portals. That's the reason why by
>   >     default the "**modern**" page functionality is not enabled on "**classic**"
>   >     SharePoint publishing portals.
> - > In June 2017 SharePoint Framework
>   >     extensions went into developer preview. Using these SharePoint
>   >     Framework Extensions you can control the rendering of a field via
>   >     custom code and you can create user custom actions that execute your
>   >     custom code. If you want to learn more about the SharePoint Framework
>   >     Extensions checkout out this link: http://aka.ms/spfx-extensions.

Answer (score -1):

You can add the script editor and content editor webpart from classic view. you can find the classic view option at bottom left of page.

[image]

Comment: Don't recommended combining the "modern" page functionality with "classic" SharePoint publishing portals. That's the reason why by default the "modern" page functionality is not enabled on "classic" SharePoint publishing portals.